# OpenOffice: программная установка пароля на изменение раздела

Tags: open-office, password

Добрый день
Как программно установить пароль для защиты раздела от редактирования?
`wiki.openoffice.org` уже курил, как поставить беспарольную защиту разобрался, но лучше все-таки с паролем...

Comment: Просто интересно. Зачем?

Comment: Программно формируемый договор с контрагентом.